# I need help with the translation of 长和能力

Tags: translation, meaning, meaning-in-context

I'm working with Chinese resumes and I've found 长和能力 as a section title. I tried to translate it using the Google Translate and it says it means "Length and capacity". Is there any alternative translation, maybe more appropiate taking into account the context?

Thank you.

Comment: Is it possible to provide more information, like what are the preceding/subsequent phase?  While the translation is correct, the sentence does not make sense to me by itself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've asked something "more appropriate taking into account the context?".

Taking consideration that this being coming from a resume, I hold that this "长和能力" is very likely to be missing a character that would have formed a word with "长". It is likely to be “长处” （"merit", "strength" or "advantage; lit. *where it's long*), making the whole “长处和能力” (Strength and Abilities), which would make sense for a resume section title.

The bad news is that this person misspelled in his resume and you might now like it; but the good news is, I will tell you that “长处” is a very tacit euphemism for a body part.

Answer (score 3):

It does not make sense. Maybe a typo. (from a copy-paste error?)

I think it should be `特长和能力` (specialties and abilities).